# How can the policeman catch the gangster?

Tags: algorithms, problem-solving, game-theory

I try to solve the following problem (Moscow Mathematical Olympiad, 1978)

> There is a town with six streets: four sides of a square and two its middle lines. Policeman tries to catch a gangster. If policeman and gangster are on the same street, then gangster will be surrender. Speed of the policeman equals 2.1 speed of the gangster. Prove that policeman can catch the gangster.

In fact, all algorithms that I can come up don't work even if speed of policeman equals 100000 speed of the gangster.

Comment: Can P see G if they are not on the same street?

Comment: This is the original formulation. But I think no, because otherwise it will be very easy problem

Comment: extremely interesting problem, have you tried posting it in artofproblemsolving ? . Another question I am curious of, if 2.1 can be substituted with any number >2, and if it makes any difference to the solution

Comment: Yes, I posted it here and at artofproblemsolving.
Also, I belive that 2.1 can be changed with 2+$\varepsilon$

Comment: Please always crosslink the posts when you crosspost; otherwise efforts may be unnecessarily duplicated.

Comment: Is there any obvious counter-example if speed of policeman is exactly two times speed of the gangster?

Comment: No problem. Also posted here: https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1248000_how_can_policeman_catch_the_gangster

Comment: @Yerken. Thought about this five minutes ago... But I think it is more difficult

Comment: I think we solved it!
In some time I will formulate it in russian and then try to translate in english.
On artofproblem solving there is the same strategy as ours...

Comment: This has just been asked again at [puzzling.SE](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36565), gaining a lot more attention and resulting in the same solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive that the following text is a solution of this problem. If someone find a mistake, it will be good (and bad, simultaneously).

So, let the square be $ABCD$ (clockwise), the midpoints of $AB$, $BC$, $CD$, $DA$ are $K$, $L$, $M$, $N$, respectevly, $O=KM\cap LN$. Let's ask the policeman use the following strategy:
$$
\ldots ONAKOKBLOLCMOMDNONA \ldots,
$$
i.e he goes clockwise around the square, runs in to check the center each time he reaches the midpoint of a side, then returns to the same midpoint and continues going clockwise.

First of all, we can observe that the gangster will never be at the point $O$. In fact, to get from perimeter to $O$ and back to perimeter takes 2 minutes but the policeman visits $O$ every $\frac{4}{2.1}<2$ minutes.

So, let us consider the set of points where can be the gangster every time the policeman visits $O$. If the policeman went $ONAKO$ then the gangster can be on the interval from point $X$ to point $Y$, where $X$ lies on $KB$ and $XB=\frac{1}{2.1}$ and $Y$ lies on $DN$ and $YD=\frac{2}{2.1}$. In fact, gangster can appear on $AB$ only when the policeman left $K$, and can appear on $AD$ only when the policeman left $A$.

By the next visit of $O$, point $X$ shifted by 2 clockwise and point $Y$ can shifted less then by $\frac{4}{2.1}<2$. So, the legth of the interval decreases every time by $2-\frac{4}{2.1}>0$ and sooner or later the length will become negative, which is impossible.

Comment: Very nice! I find it a bit easier to think of it as the policeperson going around the perimeter and visiting the centre from each midpoint; the gangster can't reach the midpoint and thus can't do better than to also travel on the perimeter; but despite the visits to the centre the policeperson is traversing the perimeter slightly faster than the gangster.

Comment: Hm... Your solution looks cool )

Comment: It's your solution; I just rephrased it :-)

Comment: I mean that it's very intresting view on it )

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution, but an observation. For simplicity assume each side of the square is 2 units long, call vertices of the square corner vertices and center of the square plus middle of each side "middle" vertices. All are crossroads. Side roads are sides of the square and other are mid-roads.

Let's say gangster at some point is at the side street, and at some point he will be located at the middle vertex. If not, he will stuck moving between two sides, and will be caught by policeman. Now assume he is at the middle vertex. WLOG it can be middle of the top side. He has to move somewhere (otherwise distance between him and police only gets smaller), and WLOG assume moving towards left side street (hence needs to cover 1 unit of distance). Hence it means that the policeman needs to be both at least (2+e) units away from both left and top sides, which is impossible.

P.S: First math problem attempted 8 years after finishing my math olympiad career :P btw, I am "Erken" on AoPS.

Comment: But the policeman don't know the moment, when he need to go to this side :(

Comment: Yup thats why this is not a solution, i wss thinking if directing policeman to follow shortest path to where gangster is at will constantly reduces the distance between two (unless gangster is not caught. If policeman alr there direct him toward current side of the gangster). Will put more thought into that later